# RequestStorageAccess - Launch Popup Window If Denied Access

Tags: macos, safari, cross-domain

I am implementing Apple's requestStorageAccess API to request cookie access in cross-domain iFrames.

One issue we are having is that Safari will block popups if not directly part of a user interaction, which makes this whole experience very unpleasant since the user needs to click on a "click this to view ..." button *twice* in order to view the site in a first party context.

### The flow (depicted below) roughly is:

- Check if we have cookie read/write access
- If so, send the POST request from the iFrame to load data.
- If not, show button with requestStorageAccess click handler.
- If requestStorageAccess resolves true, reload frame or send XHR request.
- If requestStorageAccess resolves false (we desire to launch in a new frame). Safari blocks the window.open call from the catch block though. The only other option we've found is to show a *second button* asking the user to *click again*, to launch in a new window.

Is there a better way to do this? What is the standard "failure" pattern when requestStorageAccess does not resolve to true?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some errors in example code:

1. `requestStorageAccess()` is a method of the `Document` interface: `document.requestStorageAccess()`.
2. `then()` method call is missing a closing parenthesis.
3. url inside `window.open()` must be in quotes: `window.open("appointments.html")`.

Here is your code with all the errors corrected:

```js
document.requestStorageAccess().then(_=>
{
  // load appointments
}).catch(_=> {
  // launch popup
  window.open("appointments.html");
  // safari blocks this popup since it's part of a promise it is not directly part of a click action...
});
```

Now, to make this code work, you need to move your popup opening code from `catch()` into error callback of `then()`:

```js
document.requestStorageAccess().then(_=> 
{
    // load appointments
}, _ => {
    // launch popup
    window.open("appointments.html");
});
```

Now, why this code works is because `requestStorageAccess()` promise is actually processing direct user gesture (button click) and passes it into `then()` callbacks. But apparently not into `catch()`.

> What is the standard "failure" pattern when requestStorageAccess does not resolve to true?

I can recommend reading the official [Introducing Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) blog post.

Comment: Just want to call out that the syntax in my image was pseudo-code I threw in to simply explain the possible code paths the browser could take, not the actual code that I'm using (which is why I am not hitting runtime errors when my code executes).

Anyways, that's good to know on the second parameter on the then callback, I definitely missed that. I am surprised that the catch doesn't also have the user event gesture available to it, but that's good to know nonetheless.